# JavaScript Button to Reset Drag-and-Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to create a reset button that pops up once all of the cards have been placed in their appropriate boxes.

I've tried some script from some Fiddles I've found but they wont work. I'm still somewhat new to JS/Jquery but I imagine I have to add a correct var that increments once a card is added correct and then when that var = all the # of cards it unhides a hidden popup message.

Can someone provide some help?

```
            function init() {

            $('#element_1').data( 'number', 1 ).attr( 'id', 'card'+1 ).draggable( {
              containment: '#content',
              stack: '#cardPile div',
              cursor: 'move',
              revert: true
            } );


            $('#slot_1').data( 'number', 1 ).droppable( {
              accept: '#cardPile div',
              hoverClass: 'hovered',
              drop: handleCardDrop
            } );

        }

        function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
          var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'number' );
          var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'number' );

          if ( slotNumber == cardNumber ) {
            ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
            ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
            $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
            ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
            ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
          } 
        }
```

Comment: a jsbin/fiddle would go a long way here...

Comment: can you show us the HTML code as well?

Comment: Sorry! I should have added a fiddle. here it is http://jsfiddle.net/JDH9/6haMV/1/